# Rails 6, Schema file not matching migration files after switching Git branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-branch, rails-migrations, schema.rb

Rails 6, development with sqlite3.

My schema.rb has a file that shouldn't be there: no migration files (On *current* git branch) says it should be generated. By it's name I can see it's from an earlier branch that I abandoned, and wen't back to try a different approach to building my rails app.

To double check: I get a name error when I try to access the table in the Rails Console, so it's only there in the schema file, but not in the Database itself.

Can I force rails to run and or confirm that current schema is matching the migration files and if not matching, would run the migration?

**Edit/Update:**
I need to clarify that I have 6 migration files, that I went over to make sure none of them were from the earlier abandoned branch.

(admins is the table at issue)
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`
in the rails commandline generates:
`["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "events", "admins", "details"]`
When I do `Event` I get the columns name and type. But when I do Admin I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
NameError (uninitialized constant Admin)
```

So the issue is: How do I correctly reset the database to

Comment: If I understand correctly you have no migrations, so the schema.rb should be empty, but it is not ... and you want to fix this how: get the missing migrations or make sure the database is empty again and the schema rb too?

Comment: (Will edit initial question) Sorry for not clarifying. I have 6 migration files. I am getting more suspicious that the issue is caught by GIT as it has in the ignore file : /db/*.sqlite3 I presume that means it won't add the DB into the repo, which makes sense as I have to run db:migrate on the production server (heroku).

Answer (score 1):

The schema.rb file is auto-generated from the current state of the database, so just run `rails db:migrate` to re-generate schema.rb file

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got no response from the terminal as all migrations has been run. Did some more research and will update question) thanks for suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

running rails db:migrate:reset removed seem to have fixed the issue:
My schema file does not have the 'admins' in it, and it does not show up when running `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` in rails commandline.

I believe this was caused by Git, as it has the DB in the files: `/db/*.sqlite3` and that 'admins' was created on a branch I abandoned earlier and never merged. So it was kept in the database, but the migration files were removed when I went back and created a new branch earlier on the timeline.